# How can i set the root path of Hexo theme

Tags: github, hexo

I deploy hexo on github.The path is "https://ckbaba.github.io/CKBABA/". So I set the **_config.yml** as follow

```
url: https://ckbaba.github.io/CKBABA
root: /CKBABA/
```

The source's path of the theme as following.

```
loading:
  gif: /images/theme/loading.gif
  lottie:
```

But the path is wrong as "http://localhost:4000/images/theme/loading.gif".

It should be "http://localhost:4000/CKBABA/images/theme/loading.gif"